# Tidy a dataframe that has two types of data rows

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have data that is in this format. Simple reproducible example below:

```
26/9/21 26/9/21
10:00     Paul
12:00     John
27/9/21 27/9/21
1:00      Ringo
```

As you can see, the dates have not been entered as a column, but repeat across rows on a row to themselves. Each date then has a variable number of data rows beneath it.

The output I would like would be:

```
26/9/21 10:00     Paul
26/9/21 12:00     John
27/9/21 1:00      Ringo
```

How do I do this? Tidyverse would be my preference, but Base R solutions are fine.

Code for data entry below:

```
df <- tibble::tribble(
        ~"a", ~"b",
        "26-Sep-21", "26-Sep-21",
          "10:00",    "Paul",
          "12:00",    "John",
         "27-Sep-21",  "27-Sep-21",
           "1:00",   "Ringo"
        )
df
```

Comment: While converting that `tibble` is possible, if this is being read from a CSV or similar file, is it structured any differently there? Often the initial import is the best place to fix issues like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one `tidyverse` approach -

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  #return TRUE for each date value
  mutate(row = cumsum(grepl('\\d+-[A-Za-z]+-\\d+', a))) %>%
  #get data in long format
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  #Keep only one date value
  distinct(row, value, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  #For each row
  group_by(row) %>%
  #Assign column names
  mutate(col = c('Date', rep(c('Time', 'Name'), length.out = n() - 1))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-name) %>%
  #get data in wide format keeping data in list
  pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = value, values_fn = list) %>%
  #Unnest list data as separate rows
  unnest(-row) %>%
  #Drop row column
  select(-row)

#  Date      Time  Name 
#  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
#1 26-Sep-21 10:00 Paul 
#2 26-Sep-21 12:00 John 
#3 27-Sep-21 1:00  Ringo
```